# dynamic header for list in android

Tags: android, header

[image]

some thing like the above image.
I have a huge list of data being populated from the db in a list.

i have used index adapter to index the list through fastscroll, now i want to group them alphabetically

can any one give me any idea to do this..
i was looking all over the net but not able to find a good solution

```
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
    MyIndexerAdapter<String> adapter = new MyIndexerAdapter<String>(
                        getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        list);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Your topic title doesn't match it's content

Comment: sorry i did'nt get it..I want to generate a dynamic header for the list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The [GreenDroid library](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/) can achieve it

You can install the [demo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cyrilmottier.android.gdcatalog) available in the Android Market and look at the Tweaked ItemVew part. The code is visible [here](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/blob/master/GDCatalog/src/com/cyrilmottier/android/gdcatalog/TweakedItemViewActivity.java).

[http://lh6.ggpht.com/_OHO4y8YcQbs/TQFQTfazM2I/AAAAAAAAMpQ/lgPpIKImdZw/s288/gd5.png](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_OHO4y8YcQbs/TQFQTfazM2I/AAAAAAAAMpQ/lgPpIKImdZw/s800/gd5.png)

- There is also a more lightweight solution with the Mark Murphy's [`SectionedAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/b1a6e265fe2bbf379d108c32e48cfb5c50c4addc/ListView/Sections/src/com/commonsware/android/listview).

Comment: I have used "Mark Murphy's SectionedAdapter"..thanks for this answer...its much simpler

Answer (score 0):

The way I achieved it is having an hidden textview in the row layout , then in getview I would check if the current row is the first row for the letter , if yes I would make the textview visible , else invisible ( reset reused layouts ).